# Extracting NDVI using QGIS from multiple images to Excel?

Tags: qgis, excel, statistics, image, ndvi

I created 25 images in QGIS.

Each image has different information about the NDVI of the area.

How can I extract mean, max, and min information about the NDVI from each image and put it in Excel?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Raster Layer Statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/raster_tools/rasterlayerstatistics.html). It gives you.

> Statistics [html] Analysis results in HTML format.
>
> Minimum value [number]
>
> Minimum cell value.
>
> Maximum value [number]
>
> Maximum cell value.
>
> Sum [number] Sum of all cells values.
>
> Mean value [number] Mean cell value.
>
> Valid cells count [number] Number of cell with data.
>
> No-data cells count [number] Number of NODATA cells.
>
> Standard deviation [number] Standard deviation of cells values.